# Where can I find the open source data for the tick - Amblyomma americanum collection data of the USA?

Tags: data-request, data.gov, disease

Looking for the Amblyomma americanum tick data year wise in the USA  to analyze the risk of getting disease associated with the Amblyomma americanum

Comment: What *data* are you looking for? Please [edit] your question. Hint: only using the word *data* says nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In 2015, Yuri P. Springer and his co-authors [published a county-level compilation of tick collection records](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4623429/bin/NIHMS720980-supplement-supp_table.xlsx) for the Amblyomma americanum from published literature and databases. The article describing this compilation is ["Spatial Distribution of Counties in the Continental United States with Records of Occurrence of Amblyomma americanum (Ixodida: Ixodidae)"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4623429/).

Searching for article that site this 2014 article, I also found a 2015 article ["County Scale Distribution of Amblyomma americanum (Ixodida: Ixodidae) in Oklahoma: Addressing Local Deficits in Tick Maps Based on Passive Reporting"](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Bruce_Noden3/publication/273898821_County_Scale_Distribution_of_Amblyomma_americanum_Ixodida_Ixodidae_in_Oklahoma_Addressing_Local_Deficits_in_Tick_Maps_Based_on_Passive_Reporting/links/594179b9458515a36b57258d/County-Scale-Distribution-of-Amblyomma-americanum-Ixodida-Ixodidae-in-Oklahoma-Addressing-Local-Deficits-in-Tick-Maps-Based-on-Passive-Reporting.pdf), 2015.  which provides county level counts for Oklahoma